# Adobe AIR air.navigateToURL works very strangely

Tags: air

I want to open a link in a default browser window, so I tried the method in this post:

http://sevenwire.com/blog/2009/08/26/adobe-air-opening-external-links-in-another-browser.html

But it sometimes works, sometimes doesn't. Very strange.

Is there anyway to force the air app open a link in a new default browser window/tab?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The second parameter in navigateToUrl() defines where to open the page.

If you use:

```
var url:URLRequest=new URLRequest("http://something.example.com/page.html");
navigateToURL(url,"_blank");
```

It will open the page in the new tab/page in default browser. More info at [Adobe Actionscript Reference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/package.html#navigateToURL%28%29)

Comment: Thanks for the information but I tried and it's not working. Still open in new AIR window, not my default browser window.